# Apache's SetEnvIf to another variable in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, apache2.2, setenvif

Is it possible using SetEnvIf to set a variable to the content of another variable? and if so, how?

For example

```
SetEnvIf defined_http_conf_var ^(.*)$ has_been_defined=%{defined_http_conf_var}
```

So the idea is, if inside the apache.conf or httpd conf `defined_htaccess_var` has been defined, then `has_been_defined` inside the .htaccess should now contain the value of it?

Note. This is for apache 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
# unconditionally sets defined_htaccess_var=some_value
SetEnvIf Host ^ defined_htaccess_var=some_value

# sets another var has_been_defined=<value of defined_htaccess_var>
SetEnvIf defined_htaccess_var .+ has_been_defined=$0
```

[See more details here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)

Comment: Hi, this is almost - but the problem here is that it sets `has_been_defined ` to BLANK if the `defined_htaccess_var ` is missing, the idea is it only sets this if it has a value.

Comment: ok try updated answer now. `.+` makes sure `defined_htaccess_var` is not empty